# jquery access first option of select variable

Tags: jquery

I have an dynamically created select in jquery, I would like to modify the the first option after it is created but before I append it to the dom.

e.g

```
    myselect = myselectcreationfuynction; :-- works fine
    change value and text of first option :-- bit lost here
$('#targetdiv').html(myselect); :--works fine
```

Comment: How is it created before it is appended to DOM?

Comment: Post the create function!

Comment: it's just an html variable created from a list of unique values in a table. the format returned is '<select><option></option><option value="sommevalue1">sometext1</option><option value="sommevalue2">sometext2</option> etc..</select>'

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$("select option:nth-child(1)").replaceWith("<option>10</option>");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/7/)

**Edit**

```
$("body").append("<select><option>1</option> <option>2</option><option>3</option></select>").find("select option:eq(1)").replaceWith("<option>10</option>");
```

Comment: I'm not accessing a select in the dom.
I am accessing the variable myselect before it is added to the dom

Answer (score 0):

Right after this line:

```
$('#targetdiv').html(myselect);
$('#targetdiv select>option:first').replaceWith("<option>10</option>");
```

Comment: isn't their a way to travers the variable before it is appended